# Modifying a Pandas DataFrame column based on conditions on another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

If a DataFrame has two columns:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'City':['New York', 'New jersey', 'California'], 'Population':[100000, 500000, 300000]})
```

If City is 'New York' or 'California', I want to add 1000 to the population column. I tried code but it doesn't change the original DF

```
df[(df['City']=='New York') | (df['City']=='California')]['Population']+1000
```

Please advise if there are multiple ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[(df['City']=='New York') | (df['City']=='California'), 'Population'] += 1000
```

---

The solution is *almost* as simple as replacing `+` with `+=`:

```
df[(df['City']=='New York') | (df['City']=='California')]['Population'] += 1000
```

But this will throw a `SettingWithCopyWarning`. (Further reading on that warning is [here](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/).)

Comment: @AjitKrish you're welcome! I just edited in a tiny explanation + further reading for why the most obvious fix of changing `+` to `+=` doesn't quite work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more readable solution:

```py
df.Population += df.City.isin(['New York', 'California']) * 1000
```

You can use [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) instead of that long logical expression. It returns a boolean vector which can be multiplied by 1000 and added to the population column.

Don't forget that `+` returns a new series (column of a DataFrame). If you want to modify the existing one, you'll have to assign it back with `+=`.